# R subtract min from max, second lowest from second highest etc

Tags: r

Is there a more efficient / better way to fun this function, either by making this function more flexible or else using a set of dplyr verbs I don't know about?

I'm taking a vector (mtcars$mpg) saving it as a variable and running it through this function - what this function does is subtracts the lowest value from the highest value and the second-lowest value from the second-highest value, etc. If length(mtcars$mpg) is odd, then it should omit the median value also, but I don't know how to incorporate that part.

```
vector <- function(myvector) {
  first_value <- sort(myvector)[32] - sort(myvector)[1]
  second_value <- sort(myvector)[31] - sort(myvector)[2]
  third_value <- sort(myvector)[30] - sort(myvector)[3]
  fourth_value <- sort(myvector)[29] - sort(myvector)[4]
  fifth_value <- sort(myvector)[28] - sort(myvector)[5]
  sixth_value <- sort(myvector)[27] - sort(myvector)[6]
  seventh_value <- sort(myvector)[26] - sort(myvector)[7]
  eighth_value <- sort(myvector)[25] - sort(myvector)[8]
  ninth_value <- sort(myvector)[24] - sort(myvector)[9]
  tenth_value <- sort(myvector)[23] - sort(myvector)[10]
  eleventh_value <- sort(myvector)[22] - sort(myvector)[11]
  twelfth_value <- sort(myvector)[21] - sort(myvector)[12]
  thirteenth_value <- sort(myvector)[20] - sort(myvector)[13]
  fourteenth_value <- sort(myvector)[19] - sort(myvector)[14]
  fifteenth_value <- sort(myvector)[18] - sort(myvector)[15]
  sixteenth_value <- sort(myvector)[17] - sort(myvector)[16]
  return(c(first_value, second_value, third_value, fourth_value, fifth_value, sixth_value, seventh_value, eighth_value, ninth_value, tenth_value, eleventh_value, twelfth_value, thirteenth_value, fourteenth_value, fifteenth_value, sixteenth_value))
  }

myvector <- mtcars$mpg
myvector

vector(myvector)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following @r2evans' sage advice and putting it into the form of a function:

```r
maxtomin <- function(vec, N = NULL) {
    if(is.null(N)) {N <- floor(length(vec)/2)}
    vec <- sort(vec)
    vecfin <- rev(vec) - vec
    return(head(vecfin, N))
}
maxtomin(mtcars$mpg)
```

Comment: You can save some processing (since `sort` takes time with larger vectors), you can use `myvector1 <- rev(myvector)` or just use `finalvector <- myvector - rev(myvector)`.

Comment: these are great answers thank you all 
what is this part doing?
  if(is.null(N)) {N <- floor(length(vec)/2)}

Comment: It allows you to take the first `N` values. The code that you copied above provides the default of taking half of the data, ignoring the median value if there is an odd number of observations (which would always equal zero because it would be the value minus itself).